# How to use v-model with v-for array of strings in Vuex store?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to set value in to Array in Vuex Store, but caught an error

```
VueCompilerError: v-model cannot be used on v-for or v-slot scope variables because they are not writable.
```

Is there any way to realize this? (Without creating local copy of Vuex model array in component)

My **component.vue** template

```
<q-input v-for="phone, index  in CompanyPhones" :key="index" v-model="phone" mask="(##) ### ## ##" stack-label label="Phone" />
```

My **component.vue** scripts

```
setup () {
    const $store = useStore()
 const CompanyPhones = computed({
      get: () => $store.getters['CompanySettingsModule/getCompanyPhones'],
      set: (val) => {
        $store.commit('CompanySettingsModule/setCompanyPhones', val)
      }
    })
 return {  CompanyPhones, }
}
```

Vuex module **state.ts**

```
function state (): CompanySettingsInterface {
  return {
    CompanyPhones: ['', '', ''],
  }
}
```

Vuex module **mutations.ts** function

```
setCompanyMails (state: CompanySettingsInterface, val)  { state.CompanyMails = val },
```

Vuex module **getters.ts** function

```
getCompanyPhones (state: CompanySettingsInterface)  { return state.CompanyPhones  },
```

Comment: could you try binding the v-model to phoneBooks[index]? i know this is supposed to work if the phoneBooks array was just component data, but i'm not quite sure that it would work with computed props as well. worth a try

Comment: @Liad I tried, it returns an error `[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your computed getter/setter only accepts arrays, and updating a nested value (like `companyPhones[index]`) will have the same limitations as Vue's standard reactivity. Basically meaning you'll have to replace the array with a clone of itself whenever a child is updated directly. You could do this in a method:

```
//script
methods: {
  updateCompanyPhone(v, index) {
    const { companyPhones } = this; // destructuring ES6 syntax
    companyPhones[index] = v;
    this.companyPhones = companyPhones;
  }
}

//template
<q-input v-for="phone, index  in CompanyPhones" :key="index" :model-value="phone" @update:model-value="v => updateCompanyPhone(v, index)" mask="(##) ### ## ##" stack-label label="Phone" />
```

Since v-model is only syntactic sugar you can destructurize it into the `:model-value`+`@update:model-value` (Vue3) it represents and have more control over what it does.

If this pattern reoccurs often, you can write a Higher Order Component that maintains an Array with nested values (via `value` prop and `update:value` emit, so it works with v-model), with a slot to provide it with a custom form(field) to update its nested values (and maybe some splice/push functions to add/remove items to the array).

Comment: quasar input does not have `:value` and `@input`, thats the problem

Comment: According to their own API for the Quasar Input component, it has both the value prop, and emits an input event, both mention being used by v-model.

https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input If yours doesn't work, please share the version of Quasar Framework you're using.

Comment: I read the API about `value` prop => `Model of the component; Either use this property (along with a listener for 'input' event) OR use v-model directive`, according to this I changed my code  `<q-input :value="phone" @input="e => UpdateCompanyPhones(e.target.value, index)" stack-label  dense class="full-width" color="info" shadow-text=""  outlined  label="Телефон" >`  but input does not show anything from store

Comment: The version of Quasar Framework `"quasar": "^2.0.0-beta.1",`

Comment: In Quasar v2 the event emitted is named `@update:model-value`. Read over the fact that you were using Vue 3, they changed v-model since then. (v2 docs here: https://next.quasar.dev/vue-components/input)

Comment: I did it using `<q-field>` component with its `v-slot:control` => `<template v-slot:control="{ id, floatingLabel, value, emitValue }">
          <input :id="id" class="full-width q-field__input " :value="mail" @input="e => UpdateCompanyMails(e.target.value, index)" v-show="floatingLabel">
        </template>` for my CompanyMailsArray, but there is one another problem is can not mask using quasar's masking prop

Comment: Should I change `@input` event to `@update:model-value=""` ??

Comment: Likely because masking is q-input specific. q-input knows its receiving a maskable value (String or Number), q-field can be anything. If you take the old `q-input` and replace your `@input` with `@update:model-value="v => updateCompanyPhones(v, index)"` it should work. As far as I can tell a value is being returned, not the event from the HTML5 input underneath, so no target.value required.

Comment: I changed the `:value` prop to `:model-value`, now it works!  `<q-input :model-value="phone" @update:model-value="v => UpdateCompanyPhones(v, index)" prefix="+998" mask="(##) ### ## ##" unmasked-value  stack-label  dense class="full-width" color="info" shadow-text=""  outlined  label="Телефон" >`